# Konica Minolta bizhub c3350

Tags: drivers, printing

I am a complete novice Ubuntu user. I have started using a shared business centre and the printer here is a Konica Minolta bizhub c3350. I am unable to print at present, can anyone help with getting me up and running?

I have downloaded a zip file that is supposed to be the drivers but I don't know how to do anything beyond unzipping the file! :(

Please help!!

Comment: "downloaded a zip file" Please include the link to the source of this file? Generally you need to unpack it and copy files over or compile it. If the file is for Linux (and not for Windows) there is a "readme" or "install.txt" inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

1. Unzip (extract) the driver file by double clicking on it and then clicking "extract."
2. Open the printers dialog, click "add," enter the info to locate your printer, and click "forward."
3. Choose "Provide PPD file," click the button to locate the file, and select your extracted driver.  It will be in a folder `bizhub3850.../CUPS_1.2.../english/kmC3850np.ppd`. Select that file and click "Forward."
4. Follow the rest of the prompts through.  It should now work.

Comment: Some screenshots would be nice.